# Finding the ACF and PACF

Tags: time-series

Q: Find the autocorrelation function (ACF) and the partial autocorrelation function (PACF) of the following AR(2) process up to and including lag 3:

I am trying to understand how to find the ACF and PACf of time series in general.
Is there a general equation to solve them?

$$ y_t=\frac 13 y_{t-1} + \frac 29 y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t $$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that in general for an AR(2) process $y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \phi_{2}y_{t-2} + \epsilon_{t}$, the ACF $\rho(h)$ satisfies $\color{blue}{\rho(0) = 1, \rho(1) = \dfrac{\phi_1}{1-\phi_2}}$, and

$$\color{blue}{\rho(h) = \phi_1 \rho(h-1) +\phi_2 \rho(h-2)}, \quad \text{for } h = 2,3,4,\ldots.$$

If you know [how to solve **linear recurrences**](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf), you will now be able to obtain a general formula for $\rho(h)$.

For the PACF of such an AR(2) process, recall that it is $\color{blue}{\phi_{11} = \rho(1) =\dfrac{\phi_1}{1-\phi_2}}$ and $\color{blue}{\phi_{22} = \phi_{2}}$, with $\color{blue}{\phi_{kk} = 0 \, \text{for all } k > 2}$ (in general the PACF of an AR(p) process cuts off after lag $p$).

See for example [these notes](http://www2.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp/~tanizaki/class/2014/model_analysis1/08.pdf) (or your own notes if you have some) for some reference on AR(2) processes.